# How to avoid hard drive image conversion in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

After I export and import a virtual machine the image of my hard disk .vhd is converted to .vmdk. And now the question is how to avoid it.

Comment: I think you can't avoid it because that's what import/export does.

Comment: You can convert the `.vmdk` file to a `.vhd` file using `VBoxManage.exe clonemedium --format vhd`. [source](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi)

Comment: You shouldn't need to import/export the disk image. Just copy it and you can attach it later again. VirtualBox is very easy going with drives. Just make sure it isn't mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not actually need to use the import/export feature.

The import/export feature is to convert any foreign format into or from vmdk, because vmdk is VirtualBox's native disk format. Converting to it will give you a performance increase, but it isn't necessary.

VirtualBox does have support for Hyper-V .VHD files, which means that you can just copy the files and on a new virtual box, attach them as existing storage and you are good to go. If the VHD file is already attached to a virtual machine, you can't attach it a second time, so you need to first unmount it before you can work with it again.